# d3.js vertical line on a time axis

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I am trying to graph a vertical line on a time axis using the d3js library. The x-axis is the year 2015. I'd like the vertical line to represent today (where today is always the current day). The problem I'm having is figuring out how exactly to feed the date as a coordinate in order to be graphed properly. [Here is the jsfiddle for the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/f9wd8p6s/2/)

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.domain([new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31)])
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,1000])
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(d3.time.months)
.tickSize(30, 0)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B"));

var xAxisMinor = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(d3.time.months)
.tickSize(-height)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B"));

var xAxisMinorTicks = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(d3.time.weeks)
.tickSize(-height)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%U"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "grid-background-light")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height + margin.bottom)
.attr("rx", 5)
.attr("ry", 5);

svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "grid-background")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", 30)
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "minorTicks")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxisMinorTicks)
.selectAll(".tick")
.data(x.ticks(52), function(d) { return d; })
.exit()
.classed("minorTicks", true);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "grid")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxisMinor)
.selectAll(".tick")
.data(x.ticks(12), function(d) { return d; })
.exit()
.classed("minor", true);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll(".tick text")
.style("text-anchor", "start")
.attr("x", 12)
.attr("y", 12);


// Vertical line for today

var theDate = new Date();
var today = theDate.getMonth()+1 + "/" + theDate.getDate() + "/" +     theDate.getFullYear();

svg.append("svg:line")
.attr("class", "today")
.attr("x1", x(d3.time.format("%x").parseDate(today)))
.attr("y1", height)
.attr("x2", x(d3.time.format("%x").parseDate(today)))
.attr("y2", 0);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code you just need to change the code like below,

```
svg.append("svg:line")
.attr("class", "today")
.attr("x1", x(d3.time.format("%x").parseDate(today)))
.attr("y1", height)
.attr("x2", x(d3.time.format("%x").parseDate(today)))
.attr("y2", 0);
```

to

```
svg.append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "today")
    .attr("x1", x(theDate))
    .attr("y1", height)
    .attr("x2", x(theDate))
    .attr("y2", 0);
```

d3.time.format("%x") this will return a function which takes date object as argument and it returns date string in %x format.
But you are calling parseDate function which is not available/defined.
[Refer this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)

Hope you got it, if not ask me for more.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a bit unclear on why x(theDate) works. x is a reference to my d3.timescale. How does it also act as a function where I can pass the date to it?

Comment: To add to my first comment, it functions as both an object and a function, [more reading here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales).

Comment: basically what you are doing with x(theDate) is map the value theDate and translate it into a coordinate for the x axis through the proper x scale